# "Too few parameters" error with list of values for IN condition

Tags: python, sql, parameters, pyodbc

I am querying an MS Access database from Python using the pyodbc module. I am able to do this if I query all records in a table, but when I add a where clause, I am getting an error.

This is my code:

```
wpc_ids = ['WPCMOOTEST2', 'WPCMOOTEST1']
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=P:\Conservation Programs\Natural Heritage Program\Data Management\ACCESS databases\POND_entry\POND_be.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
wpc_list = ','.join(str(x) for x in wpc_ids)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM pools WHERE wpc_id IN (%s)'%wpc_list)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ('07002', u'[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I don't get that error without the where clause, so I'm not sure what the second parameter is that I need. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM pools WHERE wpc_id IN ({})'.format(
        ','.join('?'*len(wpc_ids))), wpc_ids
)
```

Explanation:

There is a PEP about databases, PEP249, you can read it here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

This PEP defines how API of database modules should be. `pyodbc` is the database module you're using, and it is compatible with PEP249.

One of the things the PEP defines is that each module should have a `paramstyle`. `pyodbc.paramstyle` is `qmark` so that is why you use `'?'` with pyodbc. More details https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Now, instead of building a query as a string and sending it to the database, the idea is to use parameter passing, which is a way to send the query and the parameters separately... It uses the `paramstyle` to put placeholders in the query, then you pass a sequence of parameters as a second parameter to `execute`. Example:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ? AND text_col = ?'
params = (12, 'testing')
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Note that this is not mixing the params with the string. The code is passing them as two separate arguments to `.execute()`.  That means it will be the database's job to do the interpolation safely.

Since you want to pass multiple values to the query, you must generate a string containing the number of placeholders separated by comma, same number as the elements in the list:

```
','.join('?'*len(wpc_ids)))  
 # will generate ?,?,?,?,? according with length of list
```

Comment: Surely, you've been around SO a bit. Please explain to OP and future readers what you are specifically doing.

Comment: This worked when I passed the original wpc_ids list to the len() argument. when passing wpc_list to the len() argument it was counting characters since that was a string. I think I have an okay idea of what's happening here, but would love any additional explanations or links to good references about the '?' character. Is that just a wildcard for SQL, specifically?

Comment: Added some explanation, hope it is enough?

Comment: I get nervous whenever I see SQL mixed with `format`. Not sure this is the best way.

Comment: @jpmc26 In this case, it is okay, because the actual contents of the variables are not being mixed with the sql - the `format` is being used to generate the placeholders for the parameters, since the number of elements in the list is unknown

Comment: More readable as f-string? `f"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE item IN (?{',?'*(-1+len(List))})"` (won't work for an empty list).